# Google Maps MarkerClusterer

Tags: xml, google-maps, markerclusterer

I am trying to use the V3 MarkerClusterer functionality.

Loading and parsing XML from my DB no problem but the Clusterer is not working on my array??

I am just getting all my markers showing all the time!

Any help appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var marker;
   var markerArray  = [];

  function initialize() {
 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0.00,-8.6130819);
var myOptions = {
zoom: 2,
center: myLatlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var infoWindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow;       
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow     

//  PHP file to parse and retrieve database points
  downloadUrl("/php/Ventus_application2.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("CARMA");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var MTCPERYEAR = markers[i].getAttribute("MTCPERYEAR");
      var PLANT = markers[i].getAttribute("PLANT");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("LAT")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("LON")));
      var html = "<b> Total CO2 emissions: </b> " + MTCPERYEAR + "<b> Mega Tons </b><br/><br/>"+"<b> Plant Name: </b>"+ PLANT;
      var html1 = PLANT;

      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        draggable: true,
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
      });
  //marker array to allow clearin markers
   markerArray.push(marker);

      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow1, html1);
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);

     <!-- Add a listener for drag event and return lat and long --> 
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
      document.getElementById("LAT").value = this.getPosition().lat();
      document.getElementById("LON").value = this.getPosition().lng();
        });       
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      document.getElementById("PLANT").value = infoWindow1.getContent();
        });
    }
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markerArray);      
  });


function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {};
}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind.

I simply forgot to add the reference to the  markerCluster library

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
```